# Convert vertical list to array

Tags: ruby, arrays

Is it possible to convert the below to a 6 element Array:

```
uno
dos
3
4
5:ieme
6:ieme
```

Comment: Is it in a text file ? or a string ?

Comment: Or actually, I would like to know if it's possible to have this structure in code to create an Array. I know of %w(some words), but find the vertical layout clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. It is simple.

```
<<_
uno
dos
3
4
5:ieme
6:ieme
_
.split($/)
# => ["uno", "dos", "3", "4", "5:ieme", "6:ieme"]
```

If you want to use the `%w` notation with multi lines, it is possible.

```
%w[
uno
dos
3
4
5:ieme
6:ieme
]
# => ["uno", "dos", "3", "4", "5:ieme", "6:ieme"]
```

Comment: I love the second version as I'm used to `%w`, and I assume no space is needed as every new line will act as delimiter?

Comment: @Numbers Where you have stored your data ? If it is inside the text file, none of the approach will work.. First make sure the _source_ of data.